# My desktop application cannot catch the jumplist click event

Tags: c#, .net, desktop-application, jump-list

I have a desktop application. I added jumplist menu. This menu appears in the Jumplist when I right click on icon on taskbar. The issue is when I click on the menu item it does not perform any action (i.e., my app does catch it).
I took code from the following link and customize it accordingly (Note: this code jumplist also does not work also on my pc). I am using Visual Studio 2013 and windows 10.

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/103913/How-to-Create-a-Custom-Jumplist-with-Custom-Events

In Program.cs i added following code.

```
    [STAThread]
    private static void Main()
    {
        bool firstInstance = false;
        Mutex mtx = new Mutex(true, "Jumplist.demo", out firstInstance);

        if (firstInstance)
        {
            Application.EnableVisualStyles();
            Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
            Application.Run(new frmSelect());
        }
        else
        {
            // Send argument to running window
            HandleCmdLineArgs();
        }

    }

    public static void HandleCmdLineArgs()
    {
        if (Environment.GetCommandLineArgs().Length > 1)
        {
            switch (Environment.GetCommandLineArgs()[1])
            {
                case "-1":
                    MessageBox.Show(@"-1");
                    break;
                case "-2":
                    MessageBox.Show(@"-2");
                    break;
                case "-3":
                    MessageBox.Show(@"-3");
                    break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Myjumplist class has following code

```
public class MYJumpList
{
    private JumpList jumpList;


    /// <summary>
    /// Creating a JumpList for the application
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="windowHandle"></param>
    public goJumpList(IntPtr windowHandle)
    {
        TaskbarManager.Instance.ApplicationId = "MyJumplist";
        jumpList = JumpList.CreateJumpListForIndividualWindow(TaskbarManager.Instance.ApplicationId, windowHandle);
        jumpList.KnownCategoryToDisplay = JumpListKnownCategoryType.Recent;
        BuildList();
    }

    public void AddToRecent(string destination)
    {
        jumpList.AddToRecent(destination);
        jumpList.Refresh();
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Builds the Jumplist
    /// </summary>
    private void BuildList()
    {
        JumpListLink jlItem1 = new JumpListLink(Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().Location, "Item1");
        jlItem1.Arguments = "-1";

        JumpListLink jlItem2 = new JumpListLink(Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().Location, "Item2");
        jlItem2.Arguments = "-2";

        JumpListLink jlItem3 = new JumpListLink(Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().Location, "Item3");
        jlItem3.Arguments = "-3";

        jumpList.AddUserTasks(jlItem1);
        jumpList.AddUserTasks(jlItem2);
        jumpList.AddUserTasks(jlItem3);
        jumpList.AddUserTasks(new JumpListSeparator());
        jumpList.Refresh();
    }
}
```

My main form constructor has following jumplist code line

```
 jumpList = new MyJumpList(this.Handle);
```

I don't know where is wrong.
Please give me any help to apply jumplist in my applicaiton

Answer (score 0):

with more research and struggle I rearranged the code and at last I am able to make jumplist working in vs 2013 and windows 10. 
In Program.cs i used following code.

```
    private static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        if (args.Any())
        {
            try
            {
                var proc = Process.GetCurrentProcess();

                Process[] processes = Process.GetProcessesByName(proc.ProcessName);

                if (processes.Length > 1)
                {
                    //iterate through all running target applications      
                    foreach (Process p in processes)
                    {
                        if (p.Id != proc.Id)
                        {
                            if (args[0] == "Item1")
                                SendMessage(p.MainWindowHandle, Item1Value, IntPtr.Zero, IntPtr.Zero);
                            if (args[0] == "Item2")
                                SendMessage(p.MainWindowHandle, Item2Value, IntPtr.Zero, IntPtr.Zero);
                            if (args[0] == "Item3")
                                SendMessage(p.MainWindowHandle, Item3Value, IntPtr.Zero, IntPtr.Zero);

                            Environment.Exit(0);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {


            }
        }

        Application.EnableVisualStyles();
        Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);

        if (args.Any())
        {
            if (args[0] == "Item1") Application.Run(new frmSelect(Item1Value));
            if (args[0] == "Item2") Application.Run(new frmSelect(Item2Value));
            if (args[0] == "Item3") Application.Run(new frmSelect(Item3Value));
        }
        else
        {
            Application.Run(new frmSelect());
        }


    }

    [DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
    private static extern IntPtr SendMessage(IntPtr hwnd, uint Msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam);
    private const int Item1Value = 0xA123;
    private const int Item2Value = 0xA124;
    private const int Item3Value = 0xA125;
}
```

My main form shown method has the following code

```
    private void frmSelect_Shown(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var appPath = Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().Location;
        var jumpList = JumpList.CreateJumpList();
        var category = new JumpListCustomCategory("MyApp");

        category.AddJumpListItems(
            new JumpListLink(appPath, "Item1") {Arguments = "Item1"},
            new JumpListLink(appPath, "Item2") {Arguments = "Item2"},
            new JumpListLink(appPath, "Item3") {Arguments = "Item3"});

        jumpList.AddCustomCategories(category);
        jumpList.Refresh();
    }
```

WndProc method in my main form has following code

```
    protected override void WndProc(ref Message message)
    {
        if (message.Msg == Item1Value) messagebox.show("Item1 Clicked"); // here we can call relevant method
        if (message.Msg == Item2Value) messagebox.show("Item2 Clicked"); // here we can call relevant method
        if (message.Msg == Irem3Value) messagebox.show("Item3 Clicked"); // here we can call relevant method

        base.WndProc(ref message);
    }
```

I hope any body can apply this simple method to use jump list in applications.

Comment: Use the edit option on the original question to add additional information please. Answers are complete answers, not additional details.